# ¿Como solucionar Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function en ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Estoy realizando un proyecto en asp.net mvc c#, el problema que tengo es que dentro de mi controller tiene unos ActionResult que retorna una PartialView para asi poder ser mostradas dentro de una ventana modal, el problema es cuando abro la modal de registrar un nuevo producto, cuando se abre por primera vez todo funciona bien, normal. El problema esta cuando cierro y vuelvo a tratar de abrir ese mismo modal, me genera el siguiente error por consola

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
at showCreate (Usuarios:138)
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (Usuarios:159)
```

Alguien me puede decir como solucionar este error, esto me sale en todas las ventanas modal que muestran un PartialView del aplicativo, para hacer el llamado a esas PartialView lo hago mediante jquery de esta forma

```
function showCreate() {
    $('#create').modal('show');
    $('#tip').html("<p><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-spin'></i> &nbsp; Carcagndo...</p> ").load('@Url.Action("Create")');
}
```

Comment: Podrías agregar el codigo del view? también el lugar donde importas bootstrap (no sé si ese modal estás usando)

Comment: El lugar donde importo el bootstrap es el generado por defecto en la cabecera del head de la vista _Layout.cshtml, el codigo del view es del principal que contiene el modal o del registro?

Comment: Trata de compartir todo lo que puedas... este error puede ser causado por una duplicidad en jQuery... conflicto en versiones... etc, entonces entre más datos podamos ver, te podremos ayudar.